# VHDL Parametric Division Circuit - Book: FPGA Prototyping by VHDL Examples, Pong Chu

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado, test-bench

I'm trying to follow an example on my VHDL book. Its name is FPGA Prototyping by VHDL Examples, Pong Chu. It has a Divider Circuit example in Chapter 6, Listing 5. I understood the general idea of a division operation. To verify the module I wrote a testbench and I saw that it doesn't work properly. If anyone could explain to me where the problem is, I would be very appreciated. 
Here are the codes of module and testbench. 
Module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Divider is
generic(W:      integer := 8;
        CBIT:   integer := 4 );
Port ( clk, reset :         in STD_LOGIC;
       start :              in STD_LOGIC;
       dvsr, dvnd :         in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (W-1 downto 0);
       ready, done_tick :   out STD_LOGIC;
       quo, rmd :           out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (W-1 downto 0));
end Divider;

architecture Behavioral of Divider is

type state_type is              (idle, op, last, done);
signal state_reg, state_next:   state_type;
signal rh_reg, rh_next:         UNSIGNED(W-1 downto 0)          := (others => '0');
signal rl_reg, rl_next:         STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(W-1 downto 0)  := (others => '0');
signal rh_temp:                 UNSIGNED(W-1 downto 0)          := (others => '0');
signal d_reg, d_next:           UNSIGNED(W-1 downto 0)          := (others => '0');
signal n_reg, n_next:           UNSIGNED(CBIT-1 downto 0)       := (others => '0');
signal q_bit:                   STD_LOGIC;

begin
-- FSMD State and Data Registers
process(clk, reset)
begin
    if reset = '1' then
        state_reg   <= idle;
        rh_reg      <= (others => '0');
        rl_reg      <= (others => '0');
        d_reg       <= (others => '0');
        n_reg       <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        state_reg   <= state_next;
        rh_reg      <= rh_next;
        rl_reg      <= rl_next;
        d_reg       <= d_next;
        n_reg       <= n_next;
    end if;
end process;

-- FSMD Next-State Logic and Data Path Logic
process(state_reg, n_reg, rh_reg, rl_reg, d_reg, start, dvsr, dvnd, q_bit, rh_temp, n_next)
begin
    ready       <= '0';
    done_tick   <= '0';
    state_next  <= state_reg;
    rh_next     <= rh_reg;
    rl_next     <= rl_reg;
    d_next      <= d_reg;
    n_next      <= n_reg;

    case state_reg is
        when idle =>
            ready <= '1';
            if start = '1' then
                rh_next     <= (others => '0');
                rl_next     <= dvnd;                     -- Dividend
                d_next      <= UNSIGNED(dvsr);           -- Divisor
                n_next      <= TO_UNSIGNED(W+1, CBIT);   -- Index
                state_next  <= op;
            end if;

        when op =>
            --Shift rh and rl left
            rl_next <= rl_reg(W-2 downto 0) & q_bit;
            rh_next <= rh_temp(W-2 downto 0) & rl_reg(W-1);
            --Decrease index
            n_next <= n_reg - 1;
            if(n_next = 1) then
                state_next <= last;
            end if;

        when last =>
            rl_next     <= rl_reg(W-2 downto 0) & q_bit;
            rh_next     <= rh_temp;
            state_next  <= done;

        when done =>
            state_next  <= idle;
            done_tick   <= '1';

    end case;
end process;

-- Compare and Subtract
process(rh_reg, d_reg)
begin
    if rh_reg <= d_reg then
        rh_temp     <= rh_Reg - d_reg;
        q_bit       <= '1';
    else
        rh_temp <= rh_reg;
        q_bit <= '0';
    end if;
end process;

-- Output
quo <= rl_reg;
rmd <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(rh_reg);
end Behavioral;
```

Testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity tb_Divider is
--  Port ( );
end tb_Divider;

architecture Behavioral of tb_Divider is

signal clk, reset, start, ready, done: STD_LOGIC;
signal dvsr, dvnd: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal quo, rmd: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

component Divider is
    port(  clk, reset :         in STD_LOGIC;
           start :              in STD_LOGIC;
           dvsr, dvnd :         in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           ready, done_tick :   out STD_LOGIC;
           quo, rmd :           out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end component Divider;           

begin

    UUT: Divider port map(  clk => clk, reset => reset, start => start, dvsr => dvsr, dvnd => dvnd, 
                            ready => ready, done_tick => done, quo => quo, rmd => rmd);

    process
    begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        start <= '0';
        dvnd <= x"00";
        dvsr <= x"00";
        wait for 100 ns;
        start <= '1';
        dvnd <= x"C8";
        dvsr <= x"0A";
        wait for 10 us;


    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Result of Testbench:
[image: Result of Testbench]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you would like someone to help you debug, you need to say what is happening and how that is different to what you expect to happen.

Comment: It would be helpful to others to explain what you think looks incorrect. For example, "When I try to divide 0xC8 (200 decimal) by 0x0A (10 decimal) I don't get 0x14 (20 decimal)." In your testbench, I would suggest setting `start` low one cycle after you set it high, so the UUT doesn't immediately start another round of division. I would also suggest showing the UUT's internal `state_reg` and `state_next`, so you can see what state the divider is in.

Comment: Also, it's good practice to assert `reset` at the start of the simulation.

Comment: The original code (list_ch06_05_div.vhd) can be downloaded from the  book's [Companion Website](https://academic.csuohio.edu/chu_p/rtl/fpga_vhdl.html). You have the wrong relational operator in the unlabelled process following the comment `-- compare and subtract`. Yours shows `if rh_reg <= d_reg then` while the downloaded the book code (which works) shows `if rh_reg >= d_reg then`. correct answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFSr2.jpg). A typo. The narrative on page 144 2. matches.

Comment: @user1155120 How could I miss that!? Thank you for your help, it is working now :)